# setuptools downgrading in conda to enable pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pyinstaller, conda

I built a script to fetch data in a mysql database, do some calculation and output a csv/xls. I want to make it an executable to be used by my less-techy colleagues. I opted for `pyinstaller` to do that.
I'm using **Anaconda** on **Windows 7** and coding in **python 3.5**.

This is my error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pkg_resources as res
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\downsetuptool\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 61, in load_module
ImportError: The 'appdirs' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

After checking online, this `ImportError` of the `appdirs` package is a known problem and has a solution. I find that I need to downgrade the `setuptools` package to 19.2.
Here's what I tried:

- made a new conda environment with setuptools 19.2 (I called it `downsetuptools`). result: same error (indicating setuptools-27.2, not 19.2, like above)
- Reinstalled pyinstaller in this environment. result: same error  (indicating setuptools-27.2, not 19.2, like above)
- downgraded setuptools to 19.2 in the `root` environment. result: same error  (with indicating setuptools-27.2, not 19.2, like above)
- used `pip` (instead of `conda`) to uninstall setuptools and reinstall with version 19.2. Result: same error  (indicating setuptools-27.2, not 19.2, like above)
- I deleted the whole setuptools-27.2 folder and all the zip files I could find under Anaconda3 folder. Result: same error  (indicating setuptools-27.2, not 19.2, like above)

It seems the root of the problem is the downgrading not working. I am out of solutions. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked:
deleting pyinstaller and reinstalling in the downsetuptool environment.

Hypothesis: the downgrading of setuptools must be done before installing pyinstaller.